# ValidationMessage not showing in custom asp.net mvc 2 editortemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having trouble adding a validationmessage to my custom editortemplate, this is the line I am using (I've tried posting the entire template code but having no luck)

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName) %>
```

If I put the validationmessage for the model property outside of the template it works fine so I know the modelerror exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for you :)

You need to prefix the key of your property with the name of the property in the model.

For example, if your model looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to add an error message that the Child's template can see, you need to prefix the key of the error message as follows:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Child.SomeKey", "Error message");
```

In your template view of ChildModel, display the error like this:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("SomeKey")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the strongly-typed html helpers.

Example

```
<div class="editor-label"><%= Html.LabelFor(model => model); %></div>
<div class="editor-field"><%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model); %></div>
<div class="editor-error"><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model); %></div>
```

You could do the same thing without the strongly-typed helpers by using the Model ViewPage/Control property.